# How to consider as a rule-based web application

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

Anybody familiar with rule-based, could briefly explain to me. I google it and knew rule-based used as a way to store and manipulate knowledge to interpret information in a useful way. My project requirement is rule-based system. Could briefly give some functional example which is consider rule-based.

Comment: What does rule-based system has to do with web-based applications?

Comment: @userNNNN:  "Could briefly give some functional example which is consider rule-based."  Here that translates as "Can u gimme' da' codez?".  BTW - don't you think it's time you gave up the 'prison number' for a name or proper handle?

Comment: I think i understand already something like player play against computer can be consider as AI am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want an example, look at the [Jess Demo](http://www.jessrules.com/jessdemo/)